# CDI constructor-based injection with @Resource

Tags: java, constructor, cdi

Is it possible to do a constructor-based CDI injection of a @Resource type of instance?

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {

  @Resource
  private ManagedExecutorService executorService;

  @Inject
  private MyService myservice;

}
```

I would like to convert it into something like this:

```
class MyClass {

  private final ManagedExecutorService executorService;
  private final MyService myservice;

  @Inject
  MyClass(ManagedExecutorService executorService, MyService myService) 
  {
    this.executorService = executorService;
    this.myService = myService;
  }

}
```

This would make the class immutable and easier to unit test.  The problem is that since the executorService needs to be obtained via a @Resource annotation, it doesn't seem to be injectable via the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I ended up doing - I created a producer class to managed the resource object:

```
public class ExecutorServiceProducer {

    @Resource
    private ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;

    @Produces
    @Managed
    public ExecutorService createManagedExecutorService() {
        return managedExecutorService;
    }

}
```

and I created this custom annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface Managed {
}
```

and then I was able to annotate my class as follows:

```
class MyClass {

  private final ExecutorService executorService;
  private final MyService myservice;

  @Inject
  MyClass(@Managed ExecutorService executorService, MyService myService) 
  {
    this.executorService = executorService;
    this.myService = myService;
  }

}
```

This way I can unit test the class by providing my own ExecutorService (non-container managed) instance.